# Shell script isn't working correctly on crontab, works when manually called

Tags: shell, variables, cron, sh

I've got a script in sh under Solaris 5.8 that isn't working as expected and don't really know why...

The script reads a list of URLs from a file, tests them with curl and writes the output to a log file:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Logs path
LOG_DIR=/somedir/logs

# URLs file path
URL_FILE=/somedir/url

# Actual date
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`

# CURL
CURL=/somedir/bin/curl

test_url()
{
    cat $URL_FILE | grep -i $1 | while read line
    do
        NAME=`echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }'`
        URL=`echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        TIME=`$CURL -s -o /dev/null -w %{time_total} $URL`
        echo "$DATE $TIME" >> $LOG_DIR/${NAME}_${1}.log
    done
}

test_url someurl
test_url someotherurl
```

The URL_FILE has this layout:

```
somename1 http://someurl/test
somename2 http://someotherurl/test
```

The script loads the URLs from the file and then uses curl to get the total time the URL takes to load, then prints the date and the time (in ms). The problem I find is that the variable `TIME` doesn't work when called inside a crontab, but it does when called with the user itself:

```
# Output when called with the user ./script.sh
201202201018 0.035
# Output when called from crontab.
201202201019
```

If I redirect all output `* * * * * /path/to/script/script.sh 1&2 > /tmp/output`, the output file is blank.

Also I haven't been able to see any output in /var/log/syslog about it. Any clue why `TIME` variable isn't displaying correctly when called via crontab?

Comment: What does time_total mean?  Is it a ENV variable? or some curl parameter?

Comment: Its a curl parameter you pass with -w (write-out). Its defined as : `time_total: The total time, in seconds, that the full operation lasted. The time will be displayed with millisecond resolution.` The result is 0.035 (ms) in the example when called with ./script.sh

Comment: Are you positive that `/bin/sh` works exactly the same as the shell you are running this manually from?

Comment: Yes, running `./script.sh` from `sh` itself works without problems. I've tried loading `sh` and `/bin/sh` and then running the script. The output is the same, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Things you should check out:

1. Is `/path/to/script/script.sh 1&2 > /tmp/output` valid in your cron? On my machine, it would run the script with argument "1" and try to find a program called "2" to run it. Failing to find it, it creates an empty output file. I think you're looking for something like `/path/to/script/script.sh >> /tmp/output 2>&1`
2. Do you set `CURL` to the full path of curl? Cron normally doesn't have the same path information that you have.
3. Which user do you use for running cron? Could there be access restrictions to curl or the network?
4. % is indeed handled differently by cron, if it's written in the crontab. It means newline, and should otherwise be escaped. Have you been running tests with curl directly in cron? As long as you keep this in your script you should be fine.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks! Of course you're correct. I had been tracking this thing for too long and in the end confused the two. :) I rewrote that sentence altogether now.

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be that the PATH when it runs via crontab doesn't find libcurl.so.2, but I have tried `PATH=$PATH:/new/path/libcurl.so.2; export PATH` without luck inside the sh script. Any clue how to do an export of the PATH that the crontab will like when calling the script?

Comment: @Peter This confuses me a bit. I don't have libcurl.so in my PATH, but your system might work differently. You can usually modify environment variables in your crontab. Each line should either be environment settings or a cron command. You should get information about this if you type `man crontab`

Comment: Fixed at last! The problem wasn't in the `PATH` itself, the script loaded the `PATH` without problem. The problem was that the library directory needed to be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Once exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the library dir, the script works without problem.